# <go up> box in bluej

Tags: java, bluej

Every time I try and make a new project in the BlueJ environment,it just makes a purple box with the project name (in the same window).[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZe4G.png) When you double click on the purple box, a separate window opens with a  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdfVq.png) purple box. When I try to open the  box, it just opens up the window which has the project on it. There isn't any available option of deleting it.

I can still make new classes and everything else seems to be working fine. I can't seem to work out why new projects aren't being created.

[shows the project and  windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZe4G.png)
[a purple  box which pops up next to the page icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdfVq.png)

edit: Closing the project seems to do the trick.

Comment: It's ages since I used BlueJ so I'm not sure, but if you look at the title, it indicates that you're 'in' the project when the 'go-up' box is shown, which appears to be a hyperlink back to the list of projects. I don't think there's an option to get rid of the hyperlink.

Comment: You were right! It was associated with a particular project so closing that project let me make new ones. Thank you for the help.